# Update table with date conversion failing on Multi-Part Identifier

Tags: sql, identifier

Thanks to the guys with suggestions on date conversion yesterday, I now have a working SELECT script.

Unfortunately, when I try to turn it into an UPDATE script, I get the dreaded

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
The multi-part identifier "mbrProject.ID" could not be bound.
```

The entire script should insert the date from mbrProject into ProjectDates, for each matching ID (mbrProject.[ID] = ProjectDates.[Project_ID]), whilst resolving mixed US & UK format dates in mbrProject, due to users having incorrect country settings when updating the tables (not changeable from my end).

```
Update ProjectDates
SET ProjectDates.[Start_Date] =

(
select right([Start_Date],4) +  
    case 
        when len([Start_Date])=10 then 
            substring([Start_Date],4,2) + left([Start_Date],2)

        else    right('0' + left([Start_Date],firstIndex-1),2) + 
                right('0' + substring([Start_Date],firstIndex+1,secondIndex - firstIndex-1),2) 
                end

from 
    (
    select mp.[Start_Date], charindex('/',mp.[Start_Date],1) firstIndex,
          charindex('/',mp.[Start_Date],charindex('/',mp.[Start_Date],1)+1) secondIndex

    from mbrProject mp
    join ProjectDates pd
    on mp.ID = pd.Project_ID
    )A

where mbrProject.[ID] = ProjectDates.Project_ID
)
```

If I run ONLY the SELECT statement, it works fine, returning the correct values. 
i.e Everything from

```
select right([Start_Date],4) +  
    case
```

down to

```
from mbrProject mp
join ProjectDates pd
on mp.ID = pd.Project_ID
)A
```

However, as soon as I try to wrap it up in the UPDATE statement, I get the error.

I know that this is down to syntax, but wherever I try to move stuff, I can't quite figure it out.

Any ideas please?

Thanks
Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE PR
SET PR.[Start_Date] = A.[Corrected_Start_Date]
FROM ProjectDates PR
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            [Id],
            RIGHT([Start_Date],4) +  
            CASE
                WHEN len([Start_Date])=10
                THEN substring([Start_Date],4,2) + LEFT([Start_Date],2)
                ELSE RIGHT('0' + LEFT([Start_Date],firstIndex-1),2) + 
                         RIGHT('0' + substring([Start_Date],firstIndex+1,secondIndex - firstIndex-1),2) 
            END [Corrected_Start_Date]
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT
                        [Id],
                        [Start_Date],
                        charindex('/',[Start_Date],1) firstIndex,
                        charindex('/',[Start_Date],charindex('/',[Start_Date],1)+1) secondIndex
            FROM mbrProject
        ) S
    ) A
ON A.[ID] = PR.[Project_ID]
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you, Hamlet.  I had to make one minor amendment:  I got an "invalid column 'ID'" error on row 7.  Therefore, in the final FROM (SELECT... statement, I amended to SELECT [ID], [Start_Date]......  which worked perfectly.  Thanks again. Great help.

Comment: @PieEyed Yes, you right. Corrected. You are welcome. But i think there are more elegant way to solve US/UK dates format incompatibility. Look at the SQL Server `CONVERT` function with `style` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
(
select mp.[Start_Date], charindex('/',mp.[Start_Date],1) firstIndex,
      charindex('/',mp.[Start_Date],charindex('/',mp.[Start_Date],1)+1) secondIndex

from mbrProject mp
join ProjectDates pd
on mp.ID = pd.Project_ID
)A
```

At the end of the last line here, the names `mp`, `pd`, `mbrProject` and (the inner `ProjectDates`) no longer exist as table names or aliases. The only name applicable to this row set from here on is `A`, the alias you've provided.

So you need to include `mp.ID` in your select list, and then use `A.ID` in your outer comparison.

---

Also, not knowing what you're trying to do, I'd just want to make sure you're aware that `ProductDates` (the table being updated) and `pd` are referring to two separate instances of that table, an inner one and an outer one. I'm hoping that the final `WHERE` should be:

```
where A.[ID] = ProjectDates.Project_ID
```

Comment: Thanks Damien.  I tried this (whareA.[ID]...), but I just got the error "invalid column name 'ID'"

Comment: @PieEyed - to quote my own answer, paragraph 2: "you need to include `mp.ID` in your select list"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that doing

```
Update ProjectDates
SET ProjectDates.[Start_Date] = (select ...)
```

you are trying to set one field of one row to the results of the sub-select statement, which, I presume, is returning multiple values.

Comment: Yes, it needs to return a value for each row in ProjectDates, where the Project_ID value equals the ID in mbrProject.